# Works on PHP, doesn't work on PHPUnit

Tags: php, mysql, phpunit

I have a simple query which does work in a plain environment, but doesn't work on PHPUnit.

Here's the code, but I don't think it will be of any use:

```
$a = mysql_query("SELECT id,img FROM images");
$b = mysql_fetch_array($a);
```

I'm connected to the database.

The error is:

```
mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given.
```

Error is pointing to the fetch command.

Comment: check if you have a valid connection as far as I know for PHP UNIT we write code in a sub-folder and this will need a valid sql connection for doing sql operations for assert something.

Comment: You should also use Mocks for testing to not actually require the database and control returned data.  Later, DBUnit may be added for testing the Database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query failed. When queries fail the `mysql_query()` function returns `false`.

You should *always* check for errors. You should also [read the documentation](http://php.net/mysql_query) when your code does not work; it tells you what to look for.

```
$a = mysql_query("SELECT id,img FROM images");
if ($a === false) {
    die(mysql_error());
}
$b = mysql_fetch_array($a);
```

Comment: You should also switch from `mysql` to `mysqli` functions, because the mysql functions are deprecated and are getting removed.